# rails update_attribute removes the email address of an unconfirmed devise user

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Here in my code(which devise is used in it) I made the user model confirmable(i don't know if it is related or helps) and I have some `after_create` callbacks.According to my logs, before `update_attributing` the instance in the callbacks, the user instance has its email address and everything is ok but after updating it, it loses its email address!
here is my code:

```
after_create :generate_api_key

def generate_api_key
    puts "persisted? #{persisted?}"
    puts "email1: #{email}"
    api_key = ApplicationHelper::KeyGenerator.generate(64)
    update_attribute(:api_key, api_key)
    puts "email2: #{email}"
  end
```

and the result is:

```
persisted? true
email: foobar@gmail.com
email:
```

but if i disable this `after_create` callback, everything goes ok and keeps its email address!

what is the reason?

**UPDATE:** If i disable `confirmable` there will be no problem. thus the problem comes from confirmation!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why the email address is empty after updating. But i would advise you to put the generate_api_key in `before_create` so

1. You can avoid an extra database call.
2. You would want to enforce validations on update since you have the confirmable enabled.

> before_create :generate_api_key
>
> ```
> def generate_api_key
>   self.api_key = ApplicationHelper::KeyGenerator.generate(64)
> end
> ```